# Is there a way to update the TLS certificates in a net/http server without any downtime?

Tags: go, https, webserver

I have a simple https server serving a simple page like so (no error handling for brevity):

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello!")
    })

    xcert, _ := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("cert1.crt", "key1.pem")

    tlsConf := &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{xcert},
    }

    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:      ":https",
        Handler:   mux,
        TLSConfig: tlsConf,
    }

    srv.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")
}
```

I want to use a [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) TLS certificate to serve the content over https. I would like to be able to do certificate renewals and update the certificate in the server without any downtime.

I tried running a goroutine to update the `tlsConf`:

```
go func(c *tls.Config) {
        xcert, _ := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("cert2.crt", "key2.pem")

        select {
        case <-time.After(3 * time.Minute):
            c.Certificates = []tls.Certificate{xcert}
            c.BuildNameToCertificate()
            fmt.Println("cert switched!")
        }

    }(tlsConf)
```

However, that doesn't work because the server does not "read in" the changed config. Is there anyway to ask the server to reload the `TLSConfig`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is: you can use `tls.Config`’s `GetCertificate` member instead of populating `Certificates`. First, define a data structure that encapsulates the certificate and reload functionality (on receiving the `SIGHUP` signal in this example):

```
type keypairReloader struct {
        certMu   sync.RWMutex
        cert     *tls.Certificate
        certPath string
        keyPath  string
}

func NewKeypairReloader(certPath, keyPath string) (*keypairReloader, error) { 
        result := &keypairReloader{
                certPath: certPath,
                keyPath:  keyPath,
        }
        cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(certPath, keyPath)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }
        result.cert = &cert
        go func() {
                c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
                signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGHUP)
                for range c {
                        log.Printf("Received SIGHUP, reloading TLS certificate and key from %q and %q", *tlsCertPath, *tlsKeyPath)
                        if err := result.maybeReload(); err != nil {
                                log.Printf("Keeping old TLS certificate because the new one could not be loaded: %v", err)
                        }
                }
        }()
        return result, nil
}

func (kpr *keypairReloader) maybeReload() error { 
        newCert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(kpr.certPath, kpr.keyPath)
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }
        kpr.certMu.Lock()
        defer kpr.certMu.Unlock()
        kpr.cert = &newCert
        return nil
}

func (kpr *keypairReloader) GetCertificateFunc() func(*tls.ClientHelloInfo) (*tls.Certificate, error) { 
        return func(clientHello *tls.ClientHelloInfo) (*tls.Certificate, error) {
                kpr.certMu.RLock()
                defer kpr.certMu.RUnlock()
                return kpr.cert, nil
        }
}
```

Then, in your server code, use:

```
kpr, err := NewKeypairReloader(*tlsCertPath, *tlsKeyPath)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
srv.TLSConfig.GetCertificate = kpr.GetCertificateFunc()
```

I recently [implemented this pattern](https://github.com/robustirc/robustirc/commit/3b83e51eeed62e3e5421f03023503bd6e8c34193) in RobustIRC.

Answer (score 2):

I also found this nice implementation in the Kubernetes controller-runtime:
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/blob/master/pkg/certwatcher/certwatcher.go

---

I would like to add my own answer based on a simple file polling implementation. I used this for reloading certificates delivered through Kubernetes Secrets.

```
import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

type CertReloader struct {
    CertFile          string // path to the x509 certificate for https
    KeyFile           string // path to the x509 private key matching `CertFile`
    cachedCert        *tls.Certificate
    cachedCertModTime time.Time
}

// Implementation for tls.Config.GetCertificate useful when using
// Kubernetes Secrets which update the filesystem at runtime.
func (cr *CertReloader) GetCertificate(h *tls.ClientHelloInfo) (*tls.Certificate, error) {
    stat, err := os.Stat(cr.KeyFile)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed checking key file modification time: %w", err)
    }

    if cr.cachedCert == nil || stat.ModTime().After(cr.cachedCertModTime) {
        pair, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(cr.CertFile, cr.KeyFile)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed loading tls key pair: %w", err)
        }

        cr.cachedCert = &pair
        cr.cachedCertModTime = stat.ModTime()
    }

    return cr.cachedCert, nil
}
```

Comment: Is there a race condition here? What if tls.key is updated before tls.crt, and you load the new key with the old crt? I'm assuming that when a secret is updated, both  mounted files are not updated at the exact same time.

Answer (score 0):

There is: you can use https://github.com/shaj13/tlsreconciler it update  certificate including root CA and provide TLS reconciliation to connections in real time and without restarting the application.
tlsreconciler use certificate selection during the TLS handshake that tls.Config exposes.

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"

    "github.com/shaj13/tlsreconciler"
)

func HelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    w.Write([]byte("Hello World.\n"))
}

func main() {
    sigc := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    defer close(sigc)

    signal.Notify(sigc, syscall.SIGHUP)

    // Options
    sig := tlsreconciler.WithSIGHUPReload(sigc)
    certs := tlsreconciler.WithCertificatesPaths("cert_file", "key_file", "ca_file")
    verify := tlsreconciler.WithVerifyConnection()
    cb := tlsreconciler.WithOnReload(func(c *tls.Config) {
        log.Println("TLS certificates rotated !!")
    })

    config := tlsreconciler.TLSConfig(sig, certs, verify, cb)
    server := http.Server{
        Addr:      ":443",
        Handler:   http.HandlerFunc(HelloWorld),
        TLSConfig: config,
    }

    server.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")
}
```